# Check data exist or not using true/false condition by jquery on json formatted data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Hi guys I have some question concern to `json_encode` of php and jquery `$.getJSON`.

I have been try to create a notification system and I did that with the help of `php` and `jquery`.I can now fetched data from database without a page reload/refresh.

I have `fetched` data from `database` and I am displaying them in my website like :-

`Jquery` code

```
$.getJSON("notifi.php",function(data){  

$(".display_noti").empty(); // Clear out the div  

$.each(data.result,function(){  

     $(".display_noti").append("<div class='palnotific'>You got a  
          friend request from <strong>"+this['from']+"</strong><br></div>");  

   });  

});
```

On `php` side i'm just fetching data from a `table` and I `encoded` those in `json` format at end which isn't concern to my question.

This is what my php produce from that `notifi.php` file where I did my those `fetched` and `encoded` on `json` format process.

`Json encoded` format

```
{"result":[{"from":"hancy061","to":"souraan061"}]}
```

My question is now on my `jquery` side using `if and else` condition how can I check whether there is value data or not in that `notifi.php` or we can say on that `json` format data?

Comment: Did try `data.result.length` ?

Comment: bro i don't know how to check it on jquery side so..can u post some answer properly by using some true false condition for data exist or not and do some if exist and do some if not exist.I wanna use if else condition can u show me with some answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know whether `data` is returned empty json data or having data then try checking it like so :

```
$.getJSON("notifi.php",function(data){  
  // you can do checking here
  if ( data && data.length > 0 ) {
     $(".display_noti").empty(); // Clear out the div  
     $.each(data.result,function(){  
       $(".display_noti").append("<div class='palnotific'>You got a  
         friend request from <strong>"+this['from']+"</strong><br></div>");
     }); 
  }
  else {
    // do something here if no data
  }
});
```

Or maybe `data` returned some value even there is an empty data inside properties as example just returned `{"result":[]}`, then do checking it by `data.result.length`

Comment: thanks for your answer bro.It works great. :) Ya, my json data return some value too.I kept them in an array with key name `result` and `value`  where of two columns `from` and `to`.Using `data.result.length` worked perfect :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like

```
   if(data!=null && data!=undefined && data.result!=undefined && data.result.length!=undefined && data.result.length>0){
//Put your loop here
}
```

folks correct me if I am wrong here.